# What is the username of the macOS recovery?

Tags: macos, terminal, administrator

so I am trying to add a user to the admin group on my computer, but I don't have any admin powers. I do however, know the password that allows me to enter the macOS recovery mode, which I think must be in the admin group and I could use to give another user admin powers.

Does anyone know the username of this macOS recovery account?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Your question reads to me like it's an XY problem. You have a problem (X) and decide the solution is Y, and when you can't quite get Y to work you've come here asking a question about Y rather than the original problem X. Would I be correct in guessing that your actual problem is that your user account no longer has Admin privileges and you're trying to find a way to restore them?

Answer (score 1):

macOS recovery doesn't really have users or passwords. Well, technically it does have one user account: root. But Recovery's root account doesn't have a password; when you start in Recovery mode you're automatically logged in as root.

If you need to enter a password to get into Recovery mode, that's probably a [firmware password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455). If a firmware password is set, you need to enter it in order to invoke any alternate boot mode (such as Recovery). This password has nothing to do with any user name or account, and has no use after the computer has started up.